# How can I modify my regex so that it includes 1171

Tags: regex, regex-group

https://regex101.com/r/QTdaAT/1

My current regex matches all numbers that have 117 except for 1171. I am trying to modify the regex  so that it includes 1171 1711 7111. I included a link that provides examples of the matches that are made and missed with the regex I am using. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

"\b(?=[02-9]*1[02-9]*1[02-9]*\b)(?=\d{3})\d*7\d*\b"

example:

matches 1172, 1173 1174

Needs to include 1171.

Comment: What is the rule? At least one `1` and at least one `7`? `\b(?=\d*1)(?=\d*7)\d+`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match all numbers that contain at least two 1 and one 7

Then this simplified regex pattern will match them

```
\b(?=\d*1\d*1)(?=\d*7)\d+\b
```

The first lookahead `(?=\d*1\d*1)` checks for two 1 digits.
The second lookahead `(?=\d*7)` checks for a 7 digit.